# printf after scanf always displays 1 (same unexpected value)

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Okay so I'm trying to do a basic program in VS. Enter a number then it gets printed out. 1 is always printed.

```
int main(){
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    int n = scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

Comment: `int n ; scanf_s("%d", &n);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the returned value from `scanf_s()` to the variable `n`, that means that the program will print `1` in case a successful read happened.

What you should do is

```
int numberOfItemsMatched;
int readValue;

numberOfItemsMatched = scanf_s("%d", &readValue);
if (numberOfItemsMatched == 1)
    printf("%d\n", readValue);
```

I hope the variable names are self explanatory, and it's always a good idea to use this kind of names.

Comment: Note that the returned value overwrites the value written into `n` by `scanf_s()`; whatever was typed as a number is saved in `n` by `scanf()` before the function returns, but that is overwritten immediately.  You could get 0 into `n` by typing `a` instead of `31416` or whatever; you could get -1 into `n` by feeding the program from `/dev/null` or by typing the EOF indicator (control-D on Unix, control-Z on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

return type of scanf is number of items read. so if scanf is succesful in reading an item, it returns one which is assigned to n here. hence the output is 1. So separate declaration of n and scanf.